# possible to use eager loading in TypeORM with out defining a relationship?

Tags: postgresql, relationship, nestjs, typeorm, eager-loading

I want to add Creator Field to all my entities for Authorization purposes . Previously i had a OneToOne relation from every entity to User entity but now i see it is adding Constraint to that tables and eventually a user is not able to create more than a single record .
then i think of another Solution it was adding a ManyToOne relationship which it really is but the problem is that you have to add a corresponding field to User for every single entitiy you create .
like createdPosts,createdLikes,createdComments and this is also not what i need .
there is also another option to add a Creator field with a number type and leftjoin to get user every time is fetch but that add so much burden for maintenance.
so is there any built-in solution for this in TypeORM to add a Field Creator to my entities with a User Type and also have the Option to eager load it during gets and Fetchs ?

```
class User extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number; 
}
class Service extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    creator: User
 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need many-to-one on your entities that need Creator, but you do not need one-to-many on User for each of those. TypeOrm many-to-one [documentation](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations.md) specifically says "If you only care about the @ManyToOne relationship, you can define it without having @OneToMany on the related entity."

You could make this a base class to save typing this for each entity:

```
@Entity()
export class EntityWithCreator extends BaseEntity {
    @ManyToOne(() => User, { eager: true } )
    @JoinColumn()
    creator: User;
}

@Entity()
export class Service extends EntityWithCreator {
    // ...
}
```